# Devo usar dois IF's ou um operador?

Tags: if, operadores, estilo-de-codificação

Qual a melhor prática para verificar duas condições?

No exemplo que vou dar, não são verificações muito longas mas qual a melhor prática e qual é a diferença? (aconteceu comigo que dei por mim tendo um `if` enorme então decidi setorizar e dividir em vários `if`s. Isso é correto?

#### Exemplo:

```
if ( A > X AND  A > Y)
    instrucao aqui....
ENDIF
```

**Ou:**

```
if ( A > X )
    if ( A > Y)
         instrucao aqui....
    ENDIF
ENDIF
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nesse exemplo específico e só nele (se tiver uma outra forma pode não valer) costuma ser mais vantajoso fazer o primeiro, por uma razão simples: é mais simples.

Alguns até podem questionar se é realmente mais simples. Eu considero simplicidade, dentro do conhecimento que todo programador deve ter, e o uso do `AND` é necessário. Se a pessoa não o entende, pode até achar a segunda forma mais simples, mas aí é por desconhecimento.

Há controvérsias, mas para mim, mais simples é menos linhas. O código se torna mais legível quando escreve menos. Claro, não quer dizer que amontoar seja mais legível, mas colocar menos linhas dispensáveis pode se tornar mais legível. Já vi pessoas dizendo que se separar mais as coisas fica mais legível, mas se isso fosse verdade ela programaria em linguagem de alto nível quase como se fosse Assembly onde cada linha é uma única instrução.

Se tiver muitos operadores relacionais na condição pode separar em várias linhas, mas manter um único comando `if`, ainda será mais interessante.

Mas na verdade acaba sendo gosto, novamente, neste caso específico. O mais importante é ser consistente, porque é horrível ver um código que muda a forma de escrever, como ocorreu neste código.

Comment: obrigado. nesse caso mesmo as condicoes/verificações eram pequenas mas eu me deparei com condições/verificações bem grandes daí ter surgido a dúvida.

Answer (score 3):

O funcionamento das duas são diferentes, porém ambas devem funcionar.

```
if ( A > X AND  A > Y)
  instrucao aqui....
ENDIF
```

Nesse caso dependendo da linguagem ela irá otimizar a verificação consumindo menos ciclos de clocks.

```
if ( A > X )
   if ( A > Y)
     instrucao aqui....
   ENDIF
ENDIF
```

Neste outro caso ele ira verificar o primeiro entrar dentro do if e verificar o segundo. Se for uma linguagem compilada a árvore sintática será mais complexa gastando mais ciclos de clock.

Claro tudo depende da linguagem e como a mesma funciona.

No geral as duas são equivalentes ao nível de lógica, porém não a nível de execução.

Answer (score 2):

As duas verificação são válidas, porém caso haja a necessidade de dividir um if em dois o melhor é abstrair em uma função.

Caso a verificação seja simples:

```
if( A< X || B < X )
    instrução....
endif
```

Porém caso seja uma validação complexa:

```
if(valido(parametros))
    instrução...
endif

function valido(parametros)
    validação complexa...
endfunction
```

isso ajuda muito na manutenção do código, pois um desenvolvedor não precisa ler toda a validação sempre que for alterar algo nessa instrução. apenas saber que ali existe uma validação, e caso seja necessário consultar a validação é só ler a função responsável por isso.

Answer (score 1):

Em geral, acredito que seja mais fácil realizar a leitura de um único `if` ao invés de um ou mais deles.

Veja alguns cenários para compararmos as duas opções.

## Muitas condições

Pensando em casos com mais `if`s, verá que isto:

```
if ( A > X AND  A > Y AND A > Z)
    instrucao aqui....
ENDIF
```

Acaba sendo mais simples de entender que:

```
if ( A > X )
    if ( A > Y)
        if ( A > Z)
            instrucao aqui....
        ENDIF
    ENDIF
ENDIF
```

## Extrair método

Usando um único `if`, você pode simplificar o significado das condições criando um **único** método, o que não é possível com um `if` dentro de outro `if`.

Como exemplo:

```
if ( A > X AND  A > Y)
    instrucao aqui....
ENDIF
```

Você poderia ter um método `isAMaiorQueYeX(A, X, Y)`, dando um nome explicativo para a condição:

```
if ( isAMaiorQueYeX(A, X, Y))
    instrucao aqui....
ENDIF
```

Para casos de condição mais complexos, este tipo de artifício fica cada vez mais útil.

## Depuração de código e erros

Uma pequena vantagem que existe usando um único `if` é na depuração de problemas. Caso ocorra um erro de "NullPointer" ou algo parecido, a linha apontada no erro dará **direto** na condição problemática. Agora, usando várias condições na mesma linha, você não terá certeza de qual condição causou o problema e terá que depurar a aplicação para entender.

E falando em depuração, ela também é facilitada com vários `if`s. Como a depuração é feita linha por linha, fica um pouco mais fácil observar o que está acontecendo no código.